# PHPUnit - disable original constructor in Mockery

Tags: constructor, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I want use Mockery and change this:

```
$mockFoo = $this->getMockBuilder('Foo')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
```

to this:

```
$mockFoo = m::mock('Foo');
```

But I don't know how disable original constructor in Mockery. Please help me if You can. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mockery does not call constructor if no parameters are specified:

```
\Mockery::mock('MyClass');
```

**UPDATE:** The answer above was relevant for earlier versions of Mockery. With the current version one must use partial test doubles:

```php
$mock = \Mockery::mock('MyClass')->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('foo');
```

See [official documentation](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/not_calling_the_constructor.html) for more info. Credits go to [northerner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13034474/northerner)

Comment: It worked in earlier versions of Mockery. In 2023 use partial doubles for that
https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/not_calling_the_constructor.html